# Create and arrange class instances into grid

Tags: python, class, loops, data-structures

I want to arrange instances of a Room class into a grid for use in a game. Here is the class:

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, name, x, y):
        self.name = name
        self.pos = (x, y)
```

What is the best way to assign x and y values to instances so that no two instances are the same in position and the coordinates resemble a 3x3 grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import itertools
for i, j in itertools.product(xrange(3), repeat=2):
    room = Room("%s %s" % (i, j), i, j)
```

Cheers.

Comment: Can you please explain how this code works? I am not familiar with itertools.

Comment: [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is the Cartesian product of the given iterables. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: @tolo1377 Have you heard of Cartesian product? Also this link may help: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product